# Angular 2 i18n gives Translation unavailable console messages

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, translation

The early Angular documentation for i18n that I'm aware of is Stephen Fluin's example code.
https://github.com/StephenFluin/i18n-sample/commit/e2cb2006c614fce0f6d623def5f13174583233d3

I've tried to follow it closely. Atom-typescript says no errors, but I get Translation unavailable console messages for every element, like the following with < and > removed -

zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:

md-grid-tile [ERROR ->] button id="terms" md-button aria-label="TERMS" i18n="button for Terms of Service" TERMS /button  /md"): AppComponent@63:19
Translation unavailable for message id="8476fc13627507c3d0ec6b85dae533f0c5e44eef" ("-label="TERMS" i18n="button for Terms of Service" TERMS /button /md-grid-tile

My relevant code is:

**package.json**
The same as shown except I do not include @angular/tsc-wrapped because it seems unnecessary here.

**component.html** - Examples of my HTML look like:

```
<h4 id="motto" i18n="our motto stating the value of using this site">MOTTO</h4>
<md-grid-tile><button id="terms" md-button aria-label="TERMS" i18n="button for Terms of Service">TERMS</button></md-grid-tile>
```

**main.ts** I left out production environment lines & polyfills

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { TRANSLATIONS, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { TRANSLATION } from './components/navigation/language/messages.en';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(
  AppModule,
  {providers: [
  { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue:TRANSLATION },
  { provide:TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue:'xlf' },
  { provide:LOCALE_ID, useValue:'en' }
]});
```

**messages.en.ts** examples of repeated elements are:

```
export const TRANSLATION = `
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
 <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
  <body>
   <trans-unit id="motto" datatype="html" approved="yes">
   <source>MOTTO</source> <target state="translated">Find a home, save time</target>
   <note priority="1" from="description">our motto stating the value of using this site</note>
   </trans-unit>
   <trans-unit id="terms" datatype="html" approved="yes">
   <source>TERMS</source> <target state="translated">Terms of Service</target>
   <note priority="1" from="description">button for Terms of Service</note>
   </trans-unit>
```

**messages.en.xlf** again example of repeated elements

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
  <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
   <body>
    <trans-unit id="motto" datatype="html" approved="yes">
    <source>MOTTO</source> <target state="translated">Find a home, save time</target>
    <note priority="1" from="description">our motto stating the value of using this site</note>
    </trans-unit>
```

**messages.xlf** again an example of repeated elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
   <body>
 <trans-unit id="motto" datatype="html">
   <source>MOTTO</source>
   <target/>
   <note priority="1" from="description">our motto stating the value of using this site</note>
 </trans-unit>
```

Stephen's code has 40 digit hex numbers for trans-unit id s. I don't know how they were generated. My code has things like id="motto".  My console messages contain 40 digit hex, but they seem to change each time I try something.  This part is a mystery.

This is pretty bleeding edge with no real docs, but does anyone know how to fix this?  I am out of town until 10/17, but I will eagerly try good ideas when I return.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the files in Stephen Fluin's post, cited above, are generated by an Angular translation process. Do not try copy, modify, and paste - as I did above! After much searching, I found the process set up descriptions snuggled away in the Cookbook section of Angular2's devdocs. 
http://devdocs.io/angular~2_typescript/cookbook/i18n

It is a complex (for me, anyway), multi-step set up of code and translation files. But it works.  You have a choice of just in time jiT or ahead of time AoT translation. That is also a multi-step research to make a decision.  At the moment, Google suggests using jiT for development (though it is slower to paint the page) and AoT for production. AoT is currently extremely complex to set up.  Google says they are working to make it simpler. Hope that saves you some time.